# jQuery toggle on a PHP foreach statement

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, toggle

The code for the page is the following

```
<?php foreach ($organization->index() as $id=>$content) { ?>
<a href="#" id="obtain_branch"><?= $content->name?></a>
<div id="directory_brnach"><?= $content->about?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

The JavaScript code using jQuery is

```
 // Directory inner branches
$('#obtain_branch').click(function(){
   $('#directory_brnach').toggle('fast');
});
```

The problem it will only work on the first one given the the ID is not changing, the rest will not change.

How can I send an array to the jQuery function to give an individual ID on every iteration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post and highlight your code, then press the "101010" button, so that it displays correctly.

Comment: um... what exactly are you trying to do? Also mark the code as `code`. It's easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#obtain_branch` selects the first element with that ID. Using a class will help for the links, but not for the `div`s - that will toggle them all at once.
Try:

```
<?php foreach ($organization->index() as $id=>$content) { ?>
<a href="#" class="obtain_branch"><?= $content->name?></a>
<div class="directory_brnach"><?= $content->about?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.obtain_branch').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.directory_brnach').toggle('fast');
    return false; //to avoid the link from working
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IDs need to be unique. Try:

```
<?php foreach ($organization->index() as $id=>$content) { ?>
<a href="#" class="obtain_branch"><?= $content->name?></a>
<div><?= $content->about?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

with:

```
$('a.obtain_branch').click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle('fast');
   return false;
});
```